# How to get id of loaded ads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vast

I have a simple video player using Interactive Media Ads (SDKsIMA SDK for HTML5). am displaying using the VAST tag,

Here is my VAST TAG

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vmap:VMAP xmlns:vmap="http://www.iab.net/videosuite/vmap" version="1.0">
 <vmap:AdBreak timeOffset="start" breakType="linear" breakId="preroll">
  <vmap:AdSource id="preroll-ad-1" allowMultipleAds="false" followRedirects="true">
   <vmap:AdTagURI templateType="vast3"><![CDATA[https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?slotname=/124319096/external/ad_rule_samples&sz=640x480&ciu_szs=300x250&cust_params=deployment%3Ddevsite%26sample_ar%3Dpremidpost&url=https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/tags&unviewed_position_start=1&output=xml_vast3&impl=s&env=vp&gdfp_req=1&ad_rule=0&vad_type=linear&vpos=preroll&pod=1&ppos=1&lip=true&min_ad_duration=0&max_ad_duration=30000&vrid=6256&video_doc_id=short_onecue&cmsid=496&kfa=0&tfcd=0]]></vmap:AdTagURI>
  </vmap:AdSource>
</vmap:VMAP>
```

Now after ads is loaded and playing in my video player, I want to get the id of ads, this one

```
preroll-ad-1
```

Here is my solution on click

```
function onPlayButtonClick(e) {

    if($('#preroll-ad-1').length!==0){
        console.log('YES')
     }else{
       console.log('NO')
     }
  }
```

Now I am getting `NO` but the ads is loaded

Here is my live demo

[LIVE DEMO](https://royaladvastplayer.videomill.pl/)

What am I doing wrong with my code?

Comment: In your demo, no element with the ID '#preroll-ad-1' exists in the DOM

Comment: neither in any javascript I can see a reference to this id

Comment: @Brett Gregson ,  the XML file for tag url Which contain links to the loaded ID u can see it , unfortunately when I check on DOM elements its not there :( do you think is it possible to get ID of loaded ads on my video player??????

Comment: @user9964622 do you need to select by ID? Can you not just use `$("video")`, or if there are multiple video elements, use a parent ID `$("#parent video")`

Comment: YES @BrettGregson  did you try on online demo ? https://royaladvastplayer.videomill.pl/